The new fields that added to template not appear on GraphQl schema on CD server
I am using Sitecore 9.3 with JSS, I faced issue that when i add new field on template and try to retrieve it using GraphQl Query , it is coming on CM, but gives me error on CD

"message": "Cannot query field "Fieldname" on type
"DestinationPage"

, i maked sure from publishing and field in web database, the issue that the qraphql schema not updated on CD after publishing,  BTW I have separate CD and CM.
I want to reset or regenerate schema on CD after publishing.
Is there way i can do this ???

GraphQL schema auto-updates on CD after publishing. Can you check the schema provider configuration for your GraphQL host is pointing to the correct database as below.
<configuration>
   <sitecore>
      <api>
         <GraphQL>
           <endpoints>
              <edge url="/sitecore/api/graph/edge" type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Hosting.GraphQLEndpoint, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.NetFxHost" resolve="true">
                <schema hint="list:AddSchemaProvider">
                  <content ref="/sitecore/api/GraphQL/defaults/content/schemaProviders/edgeContent" param1="web" role:require="ContentDelivery"/>
                </schema>
              </edge>
           </endpoints>
         </GrapQL>
       </api>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>

Moreover you can also check the GraphQL schema for the CD server by navigating to the schema url as below:
https://{host_url}/sitecore/api/graph/edge/schema

Above url enlist the details of the schema, including templates and its fields in GraphQL.
Hope this helps!!!
